# how should I load application.scss before stylesheet_link_tag? - what's best practice in Rails5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sass, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using variable.scss to control all variables in my scss files.

In such situation, and when I want to use 'mypage.scss' **ONLY in** `mypage.html.erb` and want to use variables of `variables.scss`  in `mypage.scss`, 
what's best way to realize this?

using `<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'mypage' %>` at `mypage.html.erb` will cause error because `mypage.scss` can't get variables from `variable.scss`.
`variable.scss` should be called before `mypage.scss`.

### current situation

#### application.scss

```
# application.scss
@import 'variable'
@import 'components'
@import 'layouts'
...
```

#### mypage.html.erb

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'mypage' %> 
# error!! because I'm using many $variable in mypage.scss which defined in variable.scss.
```

In short, how should I load application.scss before `stylesheet_link_tag`?

Comment: Why didn't you add `@import 'variable'` to your `mypage.scss`

Comment: @fongfan999 I won't do that because it makes duplicate -- variable.scss --> mypage.scss --> application.scss(variable.scss included) 
It loads variable.scss twice. Is that right?

Comment: `stylesheet_link_tag 'mypage'` will replace `stylesheet_link_tag 'application'` or insert after it?

Comment: I'd like to insert after it. In my case, application.scss should be used in all pages. mypage.scss should be used in only mypage.html.erb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do that, you have to use [:content_for](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper/content_for) like this:

```
## mypage.html.erb
<%= content_for :stylesheet do %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'mypage' %>
<% end %>

## application.html.erb
# ...
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application' %>
<% yield(:stylesheet) if content_for?(:stylesheet) %>
# ....
```

---

But if you use `stylesheet_link_tag` twice, the browser will make 2 requests to load stylesheet files. It won't be a best practice. You should wrap `mypage` in a container, like this:

```
## mypage.html.erb
<div id="mypage-container">
  ...
</div>

// application.scss
@import 'variable';
@import 'mypage';
...

// mypage.scss
#mypage-container {
  ...
}
```

Comment: thanks you for the answer, I've been thinking that adding many scss files in application.scss is not good because it would make loading time longer, but including all scss file as one file is better practice( I mean, faster then adding `content_for` to each page)?